# CNAME Subdomain with Amazon S3 Bucket for Static Hosting

Tags: amazon-s3, dns

I have a bucket in Amazon S3 which is set up for static hosting called `alula-dev.sparkxr.com`.

It's working [here](http://alula-dev.sparkxr.com.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/).

I have a `CNAME` record `alula-dev`, which is set to `alula-dev.sparkxr.com.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com`

The bucket name matches the CNAME.

According to the documentation I have read, this should work, but I must have something wrong, because I've waited 48 hours for it to propagate and [alula-dev.sparkxr.com](http://alula-dev.sparkxr.com) still does not show anything. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a CNAME record alula-dev, which is set to alula-dev.sparkxr.com.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com

Let's check this.

```
dig alula-dev.sparkxr.com

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> alula-dev.sparkxr.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 18884
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;alula-dev.sparkxr.com.     IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
alula-dev.sparkxr.com.  3444    IN  CNAME   alula-dev.sparkxr.com.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com.sparkxr.com.
```

So you have an extra `sparkxr.com.` at the end of `CNAME` record.lula-dev.sparkxr.com.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com.**sparkxr.com.** Remove that and it should work.

**Update**
My bad. There are *no* extra chars, but the **lack** of dot at the end of it. So name server treats it as relative host name and  appends  $ORIGIN to it.
So, your CNAME record should be.

```
alula-dev.sparkxr.com.  3444    IN  CNAME   alula-dev.sparkxr.com.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com.
```

Note the final dot.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you. My DNS provider's interface does not show that, but when i run dig i get the same result. I have no idea how to remove that.

Comment: Updated the answer.